# Does any patch injector support Skyrim post 1.4?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I finally got Skyrim to update this morning to allow mods, but now when I run the game on 1080x5760 with eyefinity everything is messed up. Prior to 1.4 I used the patch described on [Wide Screen Gameing Forum](http://widescreengamingforum.com/dr/elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/en) (HaYDeN solution) and everything was fine. However post 1.4 the patch does not appear to fix my display anymore. Is there a new patch/method that will fix the UI?

Answer (score 3):

According to your link, Helifax's solution supports the latest patch (1.4.21.0.4).

Comment: From my interpretation the Helifax solution does not work with maps books etc. I was mostly curious if a solution similar to the HaYDeN solution.

Comment: Well, [HaYDeN did promise to take a look](http://widescreengamingforum.com/forum/forums/gaming/requestdiscuss-game-solutions/18156/skyrim-multi-monitor-user-interface-fix-disc?page=212#comment-240679) a while ago, so a new version might pop up some time soon. Until then toggling helifax's fix for world map and books appears to be the only viable solution.